# How to send an array of skspritenodes to another player in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sprite-kit, typedef, skspritenode

In my game, one player makes an array of skspritenodes in a random order that I need to send to all other players in the match.  I am not sure if this is possible or if I need a workaround that does the same thing, but in examples, I have seen a typedef struct containing pointers like the one below

```
typedef struct {

 Message message;
 NSString * piece;
 SKSpriteNode * pieces;

} MessagePieceList;
```

The code above gives me the error "ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs" when I try creating the NSString or SKSpriteNode.  I have also tried

```
__unsafe_unretained NSString * piece;
```

but then I believe I get an empty value when it reaches the other players in my didReceiveData since it is not retained. I've been able to send an integer no problem by doing the following

GameScene.m has:

```
_networkingEngine = [[MultiplayerNetworking alloc] init];
int piece = 5;
[_networkingEngine sendpiecesOrder:piece];
```

MultiplayerNetworking.h has:

```
-(void)sendpiecesOrder:(int)piece1;
```

MultiplayerNetworking.m has:

```
typedef struct {
 Message message;
 int piece;
} MessageList;
```

---

```
-(void)sendpiecesOrder:(int)piece {
MessageList messagePiece;
messagePiece.message.messageType = kMessagePieceOrder;
messagePiece.piece = piece;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&messagePiece length:sizeof(MessageList)];
[self sendData:data];
```

---

```
} else if(message->messageType == kMessagePieceOrder) {
    MessageList *messagePieceList1 = ( MessageList *)[data bytes];

    NSLog(@"Pieces order message received");
    NSLog(@"%d", messagePieceList1->piece);
```

This prints 5 when the other player(s) receives the data in their didReceiveData method.  If I cant directly send the array of SKSpriteNodes, is there a way to mold this approach so that it somehow communicates the list of SKSpriteNodes to another player?

Comment: Do struct/object to nsdictionary/nsobject to nskeyedarchive/nscoder to nsdata.  Do the opposite when decoding.

Comment: Thanks @Roecrew would you elaborate on this approach a bit?

Comment: No, I will not elaborate because you need to figure it out yourself. You'll be glad you did in the end.

Comment: No need to be a douchebag about it with the rtfm reply @Roecrew